# How to get UDP data from PC to android emulator?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, udp

I'm trying to get udp packets into android emulator sent from PC.

Server is sending udp to my PC, port number 4000, and I want to see the udp packet in the android emulator.

So i tried port redirection like:

```
redir add udp:4000:4000
```

But i can’t see the packet in the android emulator. What should i change if I want to receive the Udp packet into the android emulator?

Comment: I am in the same boat. This SO answer from 2017 indicates there might be a bug in the emulator and the redir command:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42610004/573377
and it references this open bug from 2016 with updates in 2019
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095198

Answer (score 0):

I found this open bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80149140
and their suggested workaround works for me!

> The easiest way of doing this is to run the emulator with the additional parameters:
>
> -feature -Wifi

So launching my emulator is something like this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator"
./emulator.exe -avd tablet_m-dpi_10_1in_-_api_28 -feature -Wifi
```

And pay close attention that its **-Wifi** (lowercase f and with a hyphen). You can get a list of your devices by using the command:

```
./emulator.exe -list-avds
```

And you still need to do the telnet bit after the emulator is running:

```
telnet localhost 5554
auth <your+code+here>
redir add udp:8000:8000
```